# Выбор количества скрытых узлов

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

от чего зависит выбор количества скрытых узлов в нейронной сети?

Answer (score 0):

Традиционный вопрос новичков.

Традиционный ответ на него:

https://towardsdatascience.com/beginners-ask-how-many-hidden-layers-neurons-to-use-in-artificial-neural-networks-51466afa0d3e